# Difference between attr('disabled',true) vs unbind('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable a button between the duration when it is clicked and the response arrival. My goal is to stop the onclick function getting executed if someone clicks the button again before the response has arrived.

Which is the correct function to use in this case.

```
$('#mybutton').unbind('click');
$('#mybutton').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: one is not allowing the user to click the button.other is removing the click event from button

Answer (score 2):

Disable button should be a must for a better user experience (optionally button text can be changed along with a different style), removing only `onclick` event can't provide good user experience as user can still click on the button which doesn't have any impact. Not necessarily to be followed but it can be an approach:  remove `onclick` (extra cautious) and then disable the button.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mybutton').unbind('click');
```

[unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function removes onClick event handler from the selected element.

```
$('#mybutton').attr('disabled', true);
```

This code sets a `disabled` attribute to the selected element. A disabled button cannot be clicked and is usually styled differently.

A preferred way to disallow user to click a button is to make it disabled. If some conditions change and you want to make it clickable, you can remove this attribute and don't need to attach onClick event again.

```
$(".myButton").prop("disabled", true);
$(".myCheckbox").click(function() {
  $(".myButton").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more appropriate to remove `onclick`. Disabling the field is not equivalent: browsers may add styling to it and/or not include it in the form submission, should it be submitted.

You may also find that the onclick event fires even when the button is disabled.

Comment: also how to remove the onlclick event

Comment: `unbind('click')` will remove(a.k.a `unbind`) the elements click event. You can think of disabling kind of like a style change, so it doesn't really affect the underlying behavior of the element.

Comment: There's no reason why disabled ought to affect callbacks: it's changing something about the core behaviour of the <input> element. Have you tried `off()`? http://api.jquery.com/off/